# Php look up function

Tags: php

I am trying to do an include which have a look up value.

Below is how my include looks like.

```
<?php
$output1[] = ['AB1234']['FIRST Look'];
?>
```

I am calling it like this `<?php echo $output1['AB1234']; ?>`

Everything seem to be ok just that the include file I cant figure what is the error. Any idea what is wrong here ?

Comment: That's a pretty obvious syntax error. What are you trying to do? What is `['AB1234']`?

Comment: Its a string? What could be error here then ?

Comment: The error is that `$output[] = [...][...]` is completely invalid syntax. I'm asking what you're *trying* to do, because I can't tell from that line of code.

Comment: Ok so I google the wrong thing then.

Comment: So what is best mechanism for single value look up

Comment: I can't answer that, because I still have no idea what you're trying to do. Based on the code you've posted, I think your included file should be `<?php $output = "First look"; ?>` and your including file should be `<?php echo $output ?>`. I have no idea why you're trying to use arrays here, or what you think a "look up" is.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is:

```
$output1['AB1234'][] = 'FIRST Look';
```

Then if you'll call:

```
echo $output1['AB1234'][0];
```

it'll return (print):

```
'FIRST Look'
```

By doing `$output1['AB1234'][]` you're creating a 2 dimensional array that has the first entry filled with 'FIRST Look', the structure will be:

```
Array
(
    [AB1234] => Array
        (
            [0] => FIRST Look
        )

)
```

Another way is to create an associative array by doing:

```
$output1['AB1234'] = 'FIRST Look';
```

which is equivalent to declaring `$output1 = array('AB1234'=> 'FIRST Look');` (as suggested in the other solution - only that doing it this way makes it easier to add values as you go).
The result on the second case will be:

```
Array
(
    [AB1234] => FIRST Look
)
```

and in order to print it you'll have to do:

```
echo $output1['AB1234'];
```

Comment: My +1 is pending an explanation.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I thought it's pretty straightforward but I'll add an explanationh

Comment: @Why I am getting the output printed out as Array

Comment: You have to remove the [] on the first line, right? It's just $output1['AB1234'] = 'FIRST Look';

Comment: Is this the fastest in comparison to $output1 = array('AB1234' => 'FIRST Look', 
                 'Key2'   => 'Value2',
                 'Key3'   => 'Value3',
                 'Key4'   => 'Value4'
                );

Comment: @user2711681 "Fastest" isn't relevant here. The two are not measurably different.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Since the difference between using a 2-dimensional array and an associative array might be confusing - I explained the difference between both, and showed that both of them are options.

Comment: @Marcovecchio not I don't have - this is one of two options of implementing it. Now I showed both ;)

Comment: @Alfasin ok between the 2 solution which one you suggest I mean in terms of speed measurement ?

Comment: @user2711681 I never saw any benchmark that showed difference between the executions of these two options - and if I have to guess, I bet that there isn't any meaningful difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
<?php
$output1 = array('AB1234' => 'FIRST Look', 
                 'Key2'   => 'Value2',
                 'Key3'   => 'Value3',
                 'Key4'   => 'Value4'
                );
?>
```

Then your echo will work.

Comment: How about if I just want to have individual value which will be easier for me to manage

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You just have to supply key/value pairs. If it's hard to read, just put each pair on a separate line.

Comment: Yes how have each pair on separate line

Comment: Just edited the answer to show you.

Comment: Ok its working so is this the fastest way to do a look up or any other mechanism?

Comment: In PHP, this is the fastest solution. You can create the initial list using the example, and then add / remove items freely as needed.

Comment: @user2711681 I don't think "look up" means what you think it means, and I can't figure out why you're looking for the "fastest" solution. There is no code here for which performance can possibly matter or even be measured.

Comment: Indeed, the speed concern may arise when reading the array, not when creating it. However, assuming you want a list of key / value pairs, this is the best you can do in PHP.

Comment: @Yes speed is concern for me. So this is the best suggestion is it ?

Comment: @alfasin ok I will go with this solution as its easier to add up but your earlier suggestion works too  $output1['AB1234'] = 'FIRST Look';